# Erro: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Quando tento rodar a aplicação pelo `yarn` retorna o seguinte erro:
Reinstalei o pacote `yarn add react-redux` e `npm install --save redux`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da página que esta dando erro:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer'
import Home from './Home';
import Chatbot from './Chatbot';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <Provider store ={store} >
     <div className="Conteudo">
        <Header/>
        <Home/>
        <Chatbot/>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Bom experimente deletar a pasta node_modules e adicionar o `react-redux` novamente se ja nao fez.

Comment: Tens esse `react-redux` no `package.json` e está instalado?

Answer (score 1):

Qual gerenciador de pacote você usa?

Este pacote pode estar no `node_modules`, mas se não estiver no `package.json` ou no arquivo de cache da gerenciadores de dependências/pacotes (`yarn.lock` ou `package-lock.json`).

Tente apagar a pasta `node_modules` e o arquivo de cache `yarn.lock` ou `package-lock.json`

E reinstalar as dependências.